# Bash Shell - Reading option with multiple letters

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am working on a shell script that allows users to set options.
The script is working fine if the user specifies options seperately. For instance:

```
./my_file.sh -r -l directory1 directory2
```

The command above is working perfectly, however my script doesn't work if the user specifies the following command:

EDIT: What I mean is that the `-l` option is not recognized if the user enters the command below

```
./my_file.sh -rl directory1 directory2
```

This is the code I am using to read the options

```
while getopts 'lvibrd:v' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    l) option_l=true
       shift ;;
    v) option_v=true 
       shift ;;
    i) option_i=true
       shift ;;
    b) option_b=true
       shift ;;
    r) option_r=true
       shift ;;
    d) option_d=true
       shift ;;
    *) echo "Invalid options ${flag}" 
       exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
```

Is there a way to read options with multiple letters, such as `-rl`, using similar code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Is there an error, does your computer reboot, what?

Comment: Don't `shift` in the `while getopts` loop. After the loop, you will `shift $((OPTIND-1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following (simplified):

```
while getopts 'lr' flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    l) echo "option -l was set";;
    r) echo "option -r was set";;
    *) echo "Invalid options ${flag}"
       exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
echo "$@"
```

Omitted `shift` makes the difference. The shifting confuses `getopts` builtin.

This works correctly for both single and combined options:

```
$ ./nic.sh -rl hello world
option -r was set
option -l was set
hello world
```

EDIT: I've added code to print the rest of arguments (after those processed by `getopts`).

Comment: Please demonstrate getting the rest of the command line arguments by `shift`ing at the correct place in the code.

Comment: Now I'm printing the remaining arguments, see edited code.